# WCF Soap showing the operation parameter as child level element

Tags: wcf

Soap is getting an extra child level element.

```
<Soapevn:Body>
 <ImgSrch> --Name of the operation. It takes ImgSrch_MType as parameter
   <ImgSrch_MType> -- why is this showing?. It is not a child element ImgSrch. ImgSrch is of type ImgSrch_Mtype

     <DocImgIdxArray>
     </DocImgIdxArray>
  </ImgSrch_MType>  
</ImgSrch>
</soapenv:Body>
```

It has to be

```
<Soapevn:Body>
 <ImgSrch> --name of  the operation. It takes ImgSrch_MType as parameter
     <SrchMsgRqHdr>
     </SrchMsgRqHdr>
     <DocImgIdxArray>
     </DocImgIdxArray>
</ImgSrch>
</soapenv:Body>
```

THis is the wsdl.

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="Image" targetNamespace="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://company.com">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/ImgSrch.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://somecompany.com"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IImgService_ImgSrch_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ImgSrch"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IImgService_ImgSrch_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ImgSrchResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IImgService">
<wsdl:operation name="ImgSrch">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://company.com/ws/ImgSrch" message="tns:IImgService_ImgSrch_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://company.com/ws/ImgSrchResponse" message="tns:IImgService_ImgSrch_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpEndPoint" type="tns:IImgService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ImgSrch">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://company.com/ws/ImgSrch" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Image">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpEndPoint" binding="tns:BasicHttpEndPoint">
<soap:address location="http://localhost/ImgSrch.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>

 <xsd:element name="ImgSrch" type="ImgSrch_MType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="ImgSrch_MType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="MsgRqHdr" type="MsgRqHdr_CType" />
      <xsd:element name="ImgIdxArray" type="ImgIdxArray_AType" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="IdxOnly" nillable="true" type="IdxOnly_Type" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Custom" nillable="true" type="Custom_CType" />
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:element name="Ver_1" type="Ver_1_CType" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocImgFilterType" nillable="true" type="DocImgFilterType_Type" />
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:element name="Ver_2" type="Ver_2_CType" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocImgFormat" type="DocImgFormat_Type" />
          <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="Ver_3" type="Ver_3_CType" />
            <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="lax" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>




public partial class ImgSrch_MType
{

    [DataMember]

    public DocImgIdx_CType[] DocImgIdxArray
}`enter code here`
```

ImgSrch_MType has some elements but somehow it shows up as the second to top level after the operation name. Can someone please suggest? The operation takes ImgSrch takes parameter of type ImgSrch_MType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try MessageContract, it could specify the serialized xml.

But you should pay attention that the returned type should also has the attribute MessageContract.

Below is my test code.

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName ="ImgSrch")]// specify the root element

public class Customer
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name ="DocImgIdxArray")] // specify the first child element
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
       }
[ServiceContract]


public interface ICustomerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Customer GetCustomer(Customer customer);
}
 public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public Customer GetCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        return customer;
    }
}
```

The result.
[image]

Comment: THank you for your help. That is exactly what I did to make it work.